# How to config lighttpd and fcgi for c script?

Tags: c++, c, lighttpd, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have implementing a program that using lighttp web server and fcgi(c script).
And I have searched many times but don't find any page guide to do this. Just setting lighttpd and python fcgi or php fcgi... but C fcgi.
Can anyone help me to configure lighttpd and c fcgi?
Many thanks.

I have wrote a sample as below, and build it to executable file. But now I don't know how to run it with lighttpd web server.

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int count;
using namespace std;
void initialize(void)
{
  count=0;
}

int main(void)
{
/* Initialization. */
  initialize();

/* Response loop. */
  while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0)   {
    printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
           "\r\n"
           "<title>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</title>"
           "<h1>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</h1>"
           "Request number %d running on host <i>%s</i>\n",
            ++count, getenv("SERVER_HOSTNAME"));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, lighthttp allows execute cgi scripts in directory 'cgi-bin' only.
So, just put your cgi program in '/cgi-bin' and it should work with default configuration.

This is example of cgi in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("Content-type: text/plain\n\n");
   puts("Hello from cgi-bin!...");
   return 0;
}
```

compiling

```
cc 1.c -o 1
```

Test

```
wget localhost:82/cgi-bin/1
--2014-03-20 16:27:36--  http://localhost:82/cgi-bin/1
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:82... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: `1'

    [ <=>                                                                                                                              ] 21          --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-03-20 16:27:37 (1.08 MB/s) - `1' saved [21]

cat 1
hello from C cgi!...
```

**UPDATED**

By default, you have configuration file for cgi placed here:

```
/etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-cgi.conf
```

You have to make a symlinc and restart lighthttpd

```
sudo ln -s /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-cgi.conf /etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/10-cgi.conf
```

This is what have to be inside the cgi config file

```
cat /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-cgi.conf

server.modules += ( "mod_cgi" )

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
    cgi.assign = ( "" => "" )
}
```

Comment: I have create a cgi-bin directory in /var/www/lighttpd. Then I write a sample which using fcgi library to display 'hello world' string. I build to executable file then copy this file to /var/www/lighttpd/cgi/bin. Then I entered 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/test' on browser. The binary file just downloaded but not show 'hello world'.

Comment: Here I have to use fcgi only not cgi. Which downloaded on http://www.fastcgi.com/ page.

Comment: I updated the answer. Check that you have '/etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-cgi.conf' config file and there is mod_cgi server module included.

Comment: I have install lighttpd and lighttpd-fcgi by using commands: sudo yum install lighttpd and
sudo yum install lighttpd-fcgi. But I don't see any /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/10-cgi.conf file. just has /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf file.

Comment: OK. Then just try to add the last config piece to the lighttpd.conf and restart it